# fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly;error:pack-objects died of signal 13

Tags: git

my error is follows:when I push origin dev,i got a problems,just like shows.

```
Counting objects: 4891, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4668/4668), done.
Write failed: Broken pipe90/4889), 121.78 MiB | 2.00 KiB/s    
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:zjuws/War-of-the-Ring.git'
```

Comment: ... `War-of-the-Ring`? What are you trying to host exactly?

Comment: For what it's worth, `kill -l 13` shows that signal 13 is `SIGPIPE`.  Meaning the network connection failed or something like that.  Perhaps the server side decided you're trying to do something bad, like upload a gigantic file?

Comment: thank you,I solved the problem,I uploaded a gigantic file.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTPS protocol, and increase the HTTP post buffer size from 1M to 50M.

`git config http.postBuffer 52428800`